# Running Serenity -Cucumber Test cases in parallel

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, automation, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I'm new to Serenity and BDD. I've a small demo project based on Serenity-Cucumber and Page Based model. Below is the structure of the project:

[image]

The Login and Logout features have around 8 scenarios.

**I want to be able to run the feature files in parallel. What is the easiest and most effective way to achieve this?**

So far I have

1. Created separate Runner class for each feature and then used failsafe or surefire plugin -  **This is something I don't want as I don't want a new runner for each feature file.**
2. Used the "cucumber-vm-parallel-plugin". I copy pasted below code in my pom file. Nothing happened.

   ```
   <plugin>
   <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>generateRunners</id>
           <phase>validate</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>generateRunners</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <glue>com.automationrhapsody.cucumber.parallel.tests</glue>
               <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/com</featuresDirectory>
               <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
               <format>json,html</format>
               <tags>"~@ignored"</tags>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
   ```
3. Looked into Serenity documentation and ran my program using following parameters, but could not achieve parallel execution.

mvn verify -Dthucydides.batch.count=2 -Dthucydides.batch.number=2

I'm stuck over here. Any help (easy and effective) will be appreciated. 
Also, please suggest how options 2 and 3 above can be done correctly

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Santosh please configure your pom for cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin explained in details here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41100104/2895913

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add below plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration> 
        <forkCount>5</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.class</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```