# How do i run my serenityJS tests in parallel?

Tags: cucumberjs, serenity-js

I want to run my tests in parallel so it could save time, i did find an option in serenity where we can run the tests in batch but not parallel, also cucumber-parallel seems to be promising, 
the below link is for maven project,
[Running Serenity -Cucumber Test cases in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272643/running-serenity-cucumber-test-cases-in-parallel)
Any suggestion for Serenity/JS with npm?

Comment: serenity-js is used as a plugin in Protractor? If so, then use the multiCapabilities of Protractor.

Answer (score 0):

When Serenity/JS works with Protractor, it's Protractor that you'll need to configure to run your tests in parallel.

To do that, add the `shardTestFiles` and `maxInstances` properties to the `capabilities` (or `multiCapabilities`, if you're using different types of browsers) section of your `protractor.conf.js` files:

```
exports.config = {

    capabilities: {

        // execute tests using 2 browsers running in parallel
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 2

        // ... other config
    },

};
```

Here's an [example config file](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/17feed17c3dab0398ad76ff1579f119beb8f658c/examples/todomvc-protractor-cucumber/protractor.conf.js#L40) you might find useful.

If this answer helps, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thank you!